# Phonegap app refreshes after leaving the app

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, cordova, contacts

I have an iOS app that's content only refreshes after leaving the app or double clicking the home button. it is using the contacts plugin primarily. any ideas as to why the content will only refresh after leaving the app?

Comment: to get help you should provide some details on what you're actually doing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a quick guess, if you have your code in events functions, did you put

```
   event.preventDefault();
   event.stopPropagation();
```

in your code?

Comment: no i did not, should i try to? there are many functions going on in the program

Comment: yes without that, default event is still fired and may prevent the ui refresh on some browsers. You can also add return false